# Create groups for nodes with preferences

Tags: algorithm

I have 264 children that need to be divided in 24 play groups.  Each group can contain 10, 11 or 12 children.  Further, each child can have a list of preferred playmates it would like to be in a group with. This list can be empty, or contain up to 5 children.

Finally, a child with a preference should not be in a group without any of the preferred playmates: at least one of her friends should be in the group.

I tried some pseudo code:

```
Group[11] groups;
List<Node> nodes;
int x = 264;
int nrGroups = 24;
int maxNodesInGroup = 12;
int minNodesInGroup = 10;    
foreach(Node node in nodes) {
  if(node not in any group)
    add to a group
  else
    continue

  foreach(Node preferedFriend in node.Preferred) {
    if(node not in any group) {
      //add to a same group
      continue
    } else {
      continue
    }
  }     
}
```

Is there a way to create the most ideal play groups for each child?

Comment: sounds like a homework, what have you tried so far?

Comment: Your question is unclear. You say "each node can have a preferred list of nodes it would like to be in a group." What do you mean by "would like to be"? A good start would be to write up some pseudocode that describes your algorithm as best you can, then ask for help filling in specific parts you're not able to complete yourself.

Comment: haha I can assure you it is not homework. i am an volunteer in a children vacation week. And I need to organize groups.

Comment: @Jordan tried to add some pseudo code for clarification...

Comment: Ah, see, the question would be a lot clearer if you had just said the nodes were children who can choose up to 5 friends they'd like to be in a group with.

Comment: yes you're right, sorry. Thought I keep it a bit technical talk, but that has no value here.

Comment: how to handle cases if preference is not satisfiable ? For example if 1 wants to be friend with 2,3,4,5,6. 2 wants to be friend with 11,12...15. 3 wants to be friend with 17,...20. In this case all should be in same group, but max group size is 12 only.

Comment: @Rajendran T then we should choose the most ideal group. In you're situation 1 won't be in a group with 2 but it should be in a group with 3 or 4 or 5 etc. The real life situation is that the children most of the time wan't to be in a group that overlap other preferences.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds like a [minimum k-cut](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_k-cut) problem.  Each child is a node in your graph.  The `k` connected components are your play groups.  Draw an edge between each pair of children (for a fully-connected graph).

Label an edge with `1` if one child wishes to play with the other and `0` otherwise.  Or perhaps assign more weight to edges if a child at either end has fewer preferred playmates.  Then your goal is to partition the graph in 26 distinct components, while minimizing the total "cut" edges.

Comment: ok, I have to look into thism thanks for pointing me the (probably) right way!

Answer (score 1):

If you want an optimal solution, you could try an Integer Linear Programming solver. Even though the problem is NP-hard, they are often quite fast.

You would have binary variables g<sub>ci</sub> which are 1 if child c is in group i. Then you have the inequalities for each c: Σ<sub>i</sub>g<sub>ci</sub> = 1 and for each i: Σ<sub>c</sub>g<sub>ci</sub> >= 10 and Σ<sub>c</sub>g<sub>ci</sub> <= 12. Then you have binary variables s<sub>cd</sub> for each child c that has child d on its list, which are 1 if the wish is granted. To ensure consistency between the g and s variables, you need constraints for each c, d and i: s<sub>cd</sub> <= 1 + (g<sub>ci</sub> - g<sub>di</sub>) and s<sub>cd</sub> <= 1 + (g<sub>di</sub> - g<sub>ci</sub>). This allows s<sub>cd</sub> to be 1 only if all the g values match. Then to leave no child out you have for each c: Σ<sub>d</sub>s<sub>cd</sub> >= 1. Finally, the objective is to maximize Σ<sub>c,d</sub>s<sub>cd</sub>.

This ILP has quite a lot of variables (about 7000), but there's a good chance it could be solved by solvers like GLPK or Coin CBC; also, it should be fairly easy to write a script that produces an input for these solvers for example in "CPLEX LP" format.

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer, but some further reading and my own stab at a partial algorithm.

This seems like a variation of the [stable roommates (SR) problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_roommates_problem) (itself a variation of the stable marriage problem). Two other variations that seem particularly relevant are [stable roommates problem with ties (SRT)](http://eprints.gla.ac.uk/11/1/SRT.pdf) (PDF) and the [stable fixtures (SF) problem](http://www.dcs.gla.ac.uk/~rwi/papers/newstablefixtures.pdf) (PDF). The former discusses preference lists with "ties" (like yours where all preferences are ranked equally) while the latter discusses matching groups greater than two. Both include algorithms in pseudocode which may be adaptable to your problem.

For my part it makes sense to think of your "nodes" as three distinct sets of people:

- *A*, those with no preferences
- *B*, those with exactly one preference
- *C* those with more than one preference

Intuitively it seems like *B* is the set you should consider first, since by your own specification they each *must* be grouped with the person of their preference. Taking that at a starting point, here's a back-of-the-envelope stab at an (incomplete) algorithm:

1. Divide the nodes into three discrete sets: *A*, *B*, and *C*, as above.
2. Build a set *Sb* that contains *size(B)* pairs *{x, y}* such that *x* is a person from *B* and *y* is their person of preference (a *y* may appear in several pairs). Discard *B*.
3. For any pair in *Sb* for which *y* is a member of *A* (i.e. *x* prefers *y* and *y* has no preferences), set the pair aside in *Sba*, removing it from *Sb*.
4. For any pair *{x, y}* in *Sb* for which *{y, x}* also exists in *Sb* (i.e. mutual single preference) set *{x, y}* aside in *Sbb*, and remove both it and *{y, x}* from *Sb*.
5. Build 24 sets *G(1)* ... *G(24)*. by distributing the members of *Sba* and *Sbb* in the following way:

   1. Distribute the member pairs of *Sba* among *G(1..24)* evenly, i.e. add one member from *Sba* to each of *G(1..24)*, then a second member, and so on until *Sba* is exhausted, then repeat for *Sbb* until it, too, is exhausted.

      At this point *G(1..24)* contain only "stable" members, i.e. every member of every pair is now in a group *G(n)* such that *G(n)* contains its only preference, and no *x* or *y* is in more than one group.
   2. Distribute the remaining pairs *{x, y}* of *Sb* among *G(1..24)* in the following way:

      - If *y* exists in any group *G(n)* discard the pair and add *x* alone to *G(n)* unless *size( G(n) ) = 12*.

        If the latter condition is true then add *x* to set *P*.
      - Otherwise add *{x, y}* to the first group of *G(1..24)* for which *size( G(n) ) = min( size( G(1..24) ) )* or, if all groups have the same size, add it to *G(1)*.

      At this point *Sb* is exhausted.
6. This is where things get hairy and there are many possible approaches. Just one follows.

   For each member *x* of *C* (the set of people with more than one preference) add *x* to *G(n)* where *G(n)* has more of *C*'s preferences than any other of *G(1..24)* and *size( G(n) ) < 12*. If there is a tie choose the first for which *size( G(n) ) = min( size( G(1..24) ) )*.

   If no preference of *x* exists in any of *G(1..24)* then add *x* to the first of *G(1..24)* for which *size( G(n) ) = min( size( G(1..24) ) )*.

   At this point *C* is exhausted, leaving only *A*.
7. For each member *q* of *C* add *y* to *G(n)* where *G(n)* has more members *p* for which *q* is a preference of *p* and *size( G(n) ) < 12*. If there is a tie choose the first for which *size( G(n) ) = min( size( G(1..24) ) )*.

   If none of *G(1..24)* has a member for which *q* is a preference choose the first of *G(1..24)* for which *size( G(n) ) = min( size( G(1..24) ) )*.

   At this point *A* is also exhausted and all people are a member of one and only one of *G(1..24)*. I think.

   This leaves two sets:

   - *P*, those members *x* of pairs *{x, y}* in *Sb* that we set aside because they did not  "fit" in *G(n)* where *y* was a member of *G(n)*.
   - *Q*, those members *x* of *C* that were added to one of *G(1..24)* at a time when no member of any of *G(1..24)* was a preference of *x*.
8. Let's deal with *Q* first.

   For each member *x* of *Q* (also a member *G(n)*), if *G(n)* has one or more members who are preferences of *x* then *x*'s membership is unchanged.

   Otherwise do the following:

   - If *G(n)* has any members whose **only** preference is *x* then add *x* to set *R* but leave it as a member of *G(n)* as well.
   - Otherwise remove *x* from *G(n)* and add it to *G(m)* for which *G(m)* has the greatest number of members who are preferences of *x* and *size( G(m) ) < 12*.

     If there is no such set then add *x* to set *P* but leave it as a member of *G(n)* as well.

     If there is a tie, choose the set with the most members for whom *x* is a preference. If there is *still* a tie choose the smallest set, and if there is still a tie then choose the first among them.

     Now *Q* is exhausted and we're left with two sets *P* and *R*.
9. Let's take *P*, whose members would not "fit" in any of *G(1..24)* which had any of its preferences as a match.

   For every member *x* of *P*:

   1. Add *x* to the first set *G(n)* for which *size( G(n) ) = min( size( G(1..24) ) )*.
   2. Now find the preferences *y* of *x* who are **not** in a group *G(m)* which contains another member *z* whose **only** preference is *y*. Each such *y* add to set *Px*.

      Find the person *y* in *Px* which has the most preferences who are also in *G(n)*.

      If there is a tie, choose member *y* of *Px* for whom the most members of *G(n)* *y* is a preference. If there is still a tie choose the one for whom its set *G(m)* has the fewest members for whom *y* is a preference. If there is **still** a tie choose the one whose set *G(m)* has the fewest members who are a preference of *y*. And if there is ***still*** a tie choose the one whose set *G(m)* is the largest (and if there is a tie for largest use the above criteria to choose among them, finally resorting to the first member of *Tx*).

      Add *y* to *G(n)* and remove it from *G(m)*.

      *P* is now exhausted.
10. We are now left with *R*, the set of persons *x* who have more than one preference and are in a group *G(n)* with no members who are among *x*'s preferences but who cannot be "moved" to another group because *G(n)* has one or more members *y* whose **only** preference is *x*.

    To deal with this we may try to move a member *z* who is a preference of *x* from another group *G(m)*. Of course we cannot move *z* if *G(m)* contains any member *v* for whom *z* is their only preference. If no "movable" *z* exists we may try to move the pair *{x, y}* to *G(m)* instead, or we may try to move the pair *{z, v}* to *G(n)*, but that may not be possible if *y* or *v* are similarly entangled. From there we could try triples, and so on.

In this last step (though possibly before if I've overlooked something) you may end up in a cycle, or it may be that the problem is NP-hard and no solution is guaranteed. That's a question for the Ph.Ds, I think. You may find, however, that you never end up with sets *P*, *Q*, or *R*, or that they are sufficiently small that you can just eyeball a solution. I hope this helps in some small way regardless.